# Palindrome program not giving correct output

Tags: java

OK, I know I am missing something easy here, however I cannot find my mistake. The program runs fine, it just returns the wrong message. I am not calling it properly or something. I can remove the code form the display() method and put it in the check() method and it runs perfectly. Anyone want to help out a newbie who is stuck? I was unsure if the whole program needed to be displayed, if not I am sorry. A few times before I was told I did not put enough code in. I would also like any constructive feedback on the way I have written the code, as I do not want to pick up any bad habits.

```
public class Palindrome {

    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare variables
        int number;

        // Call method
        number = retrieveInput();
        check(number);
        display();


    }// End main method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to retrieve the input
    public static int retrieveInput(){

        //Declare variables
        String number = null;
        int numInput = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        // Prompt user for input and validate that input
        while(!done){
            try{
                number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 single digits");
                numInput = Integer.parseInt(number);
                if (numInput <10000 || numInput > 99999) 
            throw new NumberFormatException();
                else 
                    done = true;
            }

            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry invalid. Please re-enter 5 single digits", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            }

        return numInput;

    }// End retrieveInput method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to determine if input is a palindrome or not
    public static boolean check(int number){

        //Declare variables
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num4;
        int num5;
        boolean isPalindrome = false;

        num1 = number / 10000;
        num2 = number % 10000 / 1000;
        num4 = number % 100/10;
        num5 = number % 10;

        // Checking to see if input is a palindrome
        if (num1 == num5 && num2 == num4);
        {
        isPalindrome = true;
        }

        if (num1 != num5 && num2 != num4);
        {
        isPalindrome = false;
        }


        return isPalindrome;

    }// End check method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to display results
    public static void display(){

        // Declare variable
        boolean isPalindrome = false;


        // Display results
        if (isPalindrome == true)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            else 
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are NOT a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }


    } // End display method 
        //************************************************************************************* 
} // End class Palindrome
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what output are you expecting?

Comment: @Kon. If it is a palindrome (12321) the result is "These 5 digits are a palindrome". If not (14578) then "These 5 digits are NOT a palindrome".

Comment: Could you change the title of your question to something that will be more helpful to people doing future searches?  Remember that the main value of Stack Overflow is the database of questions and answers that gets created for future use; not the immediate help to the original poster.

Comment: @David Wallace, will do.

Comment: on a side note i notice that when you are checking if the number is 5 digit you `throw` and `NumberFormatException` and then immediately catch it. This (the use of exceptions) is not advised for input validation as it extremely inefficient. Instead remove the `try` and `catch` statements and move the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` to where the `throw` was.

Comment: Wait, so are you saying that you're asking the same question again?  Or do you mean that you've made significant changes and have a question on a specific change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the last two lines of `main` to read

```
boolean isPalindrome = check(number);
display(isPalindrome);
```

Change the declaration of `display` to

```
public static void display(boolean isPalindrome){
```

and remove the line in `display` that says

```
boolean isPalindrome = false;
```

That way, the `isPalindrome` that `display` works with will be the same one that was evaluated in `check`.

**Edit:**

Also remove the semicolon at the end of

```
if (num1 != num5 && num2 != num4);
```

otherwise the block underneath it will run in every case, and set `isPalindrome` back to false.  Alternatively, you could just remove this condition and the block below it entirely, because it actually doesn't do anything.

Comment: It runs but give me the same results.

Comment: OK, what exactly is going wrong?  What input are you giving it, and what is coming out?  And are you certain you made ALL THREE of the changes I suggested?

Comment: Yes sir. When making the changes on the 2 lines in main, it tells me that isPalindrome cannot be resolved. That error goes away if I declare it under int number as boolean isPalindrome. Then gives me the same result as before. I can put in 66566 and it tells me it is not a plaindrome. Same if I put in 12345.

Comment: __Important:__ You must remove the semicolon at the end of the line that says `if (num1 != num5 && num2 != num4);`.  I also fixed things up so that you don't need to add that extra declaration that I missed before.

Comment: Much thanks,that did the trick. I really appreciate you taking the time to help!!

Answer (score 0):

`isPalindrome` should be in your main method and take the value from your check method. Then pass it to `display` method. The way it is now the `isPalindrome` is always false, because it is just initialized to `false` in your `display` method and never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, you did something very silly in the check method.  You say that `isPalindrome` is false, then display the value of `isPalindrome` without taking into account the fact that `isPalindrome` is calculated by a very different method and you have no way to get the value of it. What you can do is the same approach you used to get the number out of `retrieveInput` and put in `check`: function arguments. Here's a revised `display` method:

```
public static void display(boolean isPalindrome){

    // Declare variable
    boolean isPalindrome = false;


    // Display results
    if (isPalindrome == true)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        else 
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are NOT a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }


}
```

Then, the main method needs to look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Declare variables
    int number;
    boolean isPalindrome

    // Call method
    number = retrieveInput();
    isPalindrome = check(number);
    display(isPalindrome);


}
```

Comment: @tbodt, I tried it that way before I posted. When I code it that way it gives me errors in:
Main Method - display(isPalindrome) local variable not initialized. That error goes away if I add "= false" the the declaration.
Display Method - tells me that isPalindrome is a duplicate variable. I can comment it out, however the result is the same, wrong result displayed.

Comment: What happens? You seem to have been cut off.

Comment: You have repeated the mistake.  You too are setting `isPalindrome` to `false` before checking it.  If it was silly when the OP did it, what is it now?

Comment: @David Wallace  @ Kon  I have removed the variable from all of the declarations and have made it an instance variable as suggested by Kon. Still the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in that you aren't doing anything with the value you get back from `check()`. After you call it in `main()`, the value disappears since you don't assign it to any thing. Then in `display()` you create a new instance of `isPalindrome` and set it to `false`. this one has nothing to do with the one declared in `check()`. this one will always be false because you don't tell it otherwise. to fix it change your `main()` method's body to:

```
// Declare variables
int number;
boolean isPalindrome;  //declare var

// Call method
number = retrieveInput();
isPalindrome = check(number);  //assign it the value
display(isPalindrome);     //pass this value on to display
```

and then your `display` to

```
public static void display(boolean isPalindrome){

    // Declare variable
                           //don't need to decalre var as 
                           //it is now a parameter to the function
   //rest of method as before   
}
```

This will allow your display to know whether or not the number is a palindrome or not.

Edit **Also you are doing if's wrong**!

**after an if statement there is no semicolon!!**

as a a result your' if's in check do absolutely nothing and will always return false!
also keep in mind what would happen with the number 12325. it is not a palindrome but it's first and last digits are the same whereas the second and forth are. neither of your if statements would evaluate as true if they were correct. the following is the fixed code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Palindrome {
    // Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare variables
        int number;
        boolean isPalindrome; //add this var to store the value

        // Call method
        number = retrieveInput();
        isPalindrome = check(number);   //assign it so we know wheter it a palindrome or not
        display(isPalindrome);          //pass it to display() so it mknows wheter it is a palindrome or not
    }// End main method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to retrieve the input

    public static int retrieveInput() {
        //Declare variables
        String number;
        int numInput = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        // Prompt user for input and validate that input
        while (!done) {
            try {
                number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 single digits");
                numInput = Integer.parseInt(number);
                if (numInput < 10000 || numInput > 99999) {     //don't throw an error, inefecient just show the error instead
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry invalid. Please re-enter 5 single digits", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    done = true;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry invalid. Please re-enter 5 single digits", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        return numInput;

    }// End retrieveInput method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to determine if input is a palindrome or not

    public static boolean check(int number) {
        //Declare variables
        int num1,num2,num4,num5;
        boolean isPalindrome;

        num1 = number / 10000;
        num2 = number % 10000 / 1000;
        num4 = number % 100 / 10;
        num5 = number % 10;

        // Checking to see if input is a palindrome
        if (num1 == num5 && num2 == num4){  //no semicolons!!! else the if does nothing
            isPalindrome = true;            // and it evaluateds whaat it was supposed to like normal code
        }else{
            isPalindrome = false;
        }

        return isPalindrome;
    }// End check method
    //*************************************************************************************
    // Method to display results

    public static void display(boolean isPalindrome) { // no variables to declare as it now a parameter
        // Display results
        if (isPalindrome == true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "These 5  digits are NOT a palindrome", "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } // End display method 
    //************************************************************************************* 
} // End class Palindrome
```

Comment: Thanks @vandale, I appreciate the feedback!!